# Promise in NodeJS - with loop and multiple calls

Tags: node.js, promise

below is the code i try to run. sample code it is. The problem i face is, somehow it doesn't work in the order i expect. Due to it, test1 and test2 enter script at same time and messes up all.

```
 let testmap = testDataArray.map((testdataContent) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log(testdataContent)
        logger.info(testdataContent + "to be stored");
        return service1.upload(testdataContent).then((testdataUpload) => {
          logger.info(testdataContent + " is stored ");
          logger.info(testdataContent + " to  be run on script");
          return service2.runScript(testdataContent).then((scriptresponse) => {
            logger.info(testDataName + " successfully run on script");
            resolve(scriptresponse);
          }).catch((err) => {
            reject(err);
          })
        }).catch((err) => {
          reject(err);
        })
      })
    })
    

Promise.all(testmap).then((res) => {
  console.log("Done all");
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
})
```

Logger is like:

```
"Test1 to be Stored"
"Test2 to be stored"
"Test1 is stored"
"Test1 to be run on script"
"Test1 successfully run on script"
"Test 2 successfully run on script"
"Done all"
```

Order expected:

```
"Test1 to be Stored"
"Test1 is stored"
"Test1 to be run on script"
"Test1 successfully run on script"
"Test2 to be Stored"
"Test2 is stored"
"Test2 to be run on script"
"Test2 successfully run on script"
"Done all"
```

Comment: resolve promise individually inside for(let i=0; i<testmap.length; i++) loop

Answer (score 0):

You could call it sequentially in a for loop nested in a async function

```
const run = async (arrOfPromises) => {
  try {
    for (const promise of arrOfPromises) {
      await promise
    }
    console.log('Done')
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}

run(testmap)
```

Full code

```
let testmap = testDataArray.map(testdataContent => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(testdataContent)
    logger.info(testdataContent + 'to be stored')
    return service1
      .upload(testdataContent)
      .then(testdataUpload => {
        logger.info(testdataContent + ' is stored ')
        logger.info(testdataContent + ' to  be run on script')
        return service2
          .runScript(testdataContent)
          .then(scriptresponse => {
            logger.info(testDataName + ' successfully run on script')
            resolve(scriptresponse)
          })
          .catch(err => {
            reject(err)
          })
      })
      .catch(err => {
        reject(err)
      })
  })
})

const run = async (arrOfPromises) => {
  try {
    for (const promise of arrOfPromises) {
      await promise
    }
    console.log('Done')
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}

run(testmap)
```